# jQuery running before PHP has finished

Tags: php, jquery, css, css-selectors

I have a `for` loop in PHP that creates four `div`, each containing a `img` and `p` string, as below:

```
<div class="guest-tile-holder">             
    <img class="guest-tile" src="<?php echo($tile); ?>">
    <p><span><?php echo($fn.' '.$ln); ?></span></p>
</div>
```

In jQuery, I want to colour every fourth `p` black, i.e. only the `p` string the fourth box created, as below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('p:nth-child(4)').css('color', 'black');
});
```

What I would expect is that the PHP would pre-process, creating four `div` as above and then jQuery would colour black the `p` string in the fourth `div`. What is actually happening however is jQuery appears to be ignoring the PHP and colouring a `p` string that is another three `p` strings away in my HTML.

I was always led to believe that PHP would pre-process, therefore I don't understand why jQuery appears to be running before the PHP has completed.

Can anybody tell me how I would get the jQuery to run after PHP has finished?

Comment: Yeah right, your clientside code runs before the serverside code has completed, would be cool! The problem is probably that the paragraphs are not the elements you should be targeting, the parent div is, as that is where the index would be

Comment: @Ryan Can you tell me how I would get the jQuery to run **before** PHP has finished?!

Comment: Well you can try to use ans setTimeout to fire the jquery.

Comment: @JonathanRomer - No! The OP is mis-interpreting what's happening. Never try hacking something before you've at least tried figuring out what's going on.

Comment: why dont you try putting your jquery after the php code?

Comment: @user1463541 - +1 Best comment all day, really cracked me up ?

Comment: @adeneo the problem is we don't know whether it's sarkasm...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your jQuery is correctly executed after your PHP code, it's just that you're not selecting the right `p`.

`p:nth-child(4)` will select the paragraph which is the 4th element in the hierarchy. For example, the first `p` would be the 3rd element since it is preceded by a `div` and an `img`. What you're actually looking for is something like `p:nth-of-type(4)` or `.guest-tile-holder:nth-child(4)` or even using jQuery's custom [`:eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) selector:

```
$('.guest-tile-holder:eq(3) p').css('color', 'black');
```

(Since JavaScript arrays use zero-based indexing, the 4th element has index 3.)

Comment: Thanks. It ended up that your explanation was more important than the example code. I guess I just need to understand how `nth-child` works before I start believing it's not working how I'd hoped. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The index is based on elements within the same parent element, so you'll need to target the parent `div` element, if they are on the same level in the DOM, and use the `nth-child` selector on that element, and then find the paragraph and change it's CSS :

```
$('div.guest-tile-holder:nth-child(4)').find('p').css('color', 'black');
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to use find, you can simply do:

```
$('div.guest-tile-holder:nth-child(4) p').css('color', 'black');
```

Comment: Great simplification of the `.find()` example.